# I'm having one grid view in asp.net c# and I want to enable one label which can show details of particular row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having one grid view in asp.net c# and I want to enable one label which can show details of particular row.
I'm having list of persons and I want one lable "click" to show all the details of the person in grid view.
I tried serching in the net but I didn't find anything yet

Comment: please put some code(you are trying) here for better understanding.

Comment: if label text is `click` then it is probably a `button` not a `label`.

Comment: your should better use linkbutton or button in place of label if you want it clickable

Comment: where do you want to display the details at the same page or you want to redirect to other page and then want to display the details?? Or you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057791/gridview-with-detail-rows-for-each-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of label you can try the following code in asp.net

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl1 = (Label)(((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as DataListItem).FindControl("Label14");
    Response.Redirect("ShowUser.aspx?uid=" + lbl1.Text);
}
```

you can create one new page to show all the details of the user. you can build your login accordingly, I've implemented this logic in my code.

hope this will help you.

Comment: why downvoted? he is asking for functionality like this

Answer (score 2):

why using a label? you can simply use a linkbutton and set it's CommandArgument to Eval("yourgridID") also give it a commandName such as "showDetails".

and in the commandrow of the grid view you can do this with following codes:

```
if(e.CommandName=="showDetails"){
int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
var personrow=(from c in .....Your linq).First();
MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);//show your person details in this view
}
```